# What is the different between MongoDB plugins for Play framework2?

Tags: mongodb, playframework-2.0, jackson, morphia, jongo

I'm starting to learn `MongoDB`, integrated with `Play framework 2`. I goggled about how to integrate it with `Play framework2` and finally found many `plugins` available:

- [MongoDB Jackson Mapper](https://github.com/vznet/play-mongo-jackson-mapper)
- [Jongo](https://github.com/bguerout/jongo)
- [Play2 Morphia plugin](https://github.com/leodagdag/play2-morphia-plugin)

I'm quite confused which one should be used in order to organize my `MongoDB`. I was trying to search about how different between them, however, cannot find any document. So, If anyone has some experience about them, could you please share you opinion or explain the most different between them?

Comment: Oh, don't forget [ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/). It has a [Play plugin](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo) which contains [a methodology that automatically converts](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo#play2-controller-sample-using-json-writes-and-reads) between MongoDB BSON documents and Play's new, magic JSON stuff.

Comment: and to add to Carson - ReactiveMongo was actually developed by the Play team, for internal usage.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGZkmL_v1Ns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jongo](http://jongo.org) is an API to query in Java as in MongoDB Shell and uses Jackson to map documents to POJOs. This API is a tiny layer over the official mongodb-java-driver

[ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/) is a Scala driver (mongodb-java-driver is not used) created by the play framework team to query MongoDB in a real reactive approach.

Both Jongo and ReactiveMongo projects have a play plugin :

Play-jongo : https://github.com/alexanderjarvis/play-jongo

Play-ReactiveMongo : https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo

Well so, if you are looking for an easy way to query MongoDB you can use Jongo, if you are looking for a play-style reactive approach, you can use ReactiveMongo but IHMO you should test both and use the one you are more confortable with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there ReactiveMongo for Java? I'm using Play for Java or Is there any `Play2-Jongo` tutorial?

Comment: You can find more informations about how to use jongo plugin here : https://github.com/alexanderjarvis/play-jongo#usage

Comment: I can be wrong but I don't think ReactiveMongo has a Java API. Just to be sure, you can ask it here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/reactivemongo